# How can I display the Gerrit ID in the UI?

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit used to show the ID as the first column in the UI.  I'm on version 2.9 (yeah, I know, oldish, but we can't upgrade at the current time), and it's no longer visible.  I know I can click on a change and see the ID or hover over a change and see it in the URL in the browser status line, but I really need to be able to see a bunch of them at a glance.

Is there any way to augment the URL I use to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your preferences (i.e. `your-gerrit.com/#/settings/preferences`) and check the *Show Change Number In Changes Table* option.

<strike>As I can see in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2646) it was introduced in 2.10 but I remember using it earlier, if I'm not mistaken.</strike>

EDIT:
The change that itroduces it is [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/56641/) and it's included in 2.10. You will have to update in order to get the Change-Id column in the list.

EDIT 2:
I have created a simple JS script that will show the column with ChangeId. Just paste it to the URL bar when you are viewing the changes list:

```
javascript:var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("cSUBJECT"); for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) { var id = cols[i].children[0].getAttribute('href').substr(cols[0].children[0].getAttribute('href').lastIndexOf('/') + 1); cols[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<td>' + id + '</td>'); } document.getElementsByClassName("iconHeader")[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<td class="iconHeader"></td>');
```

You can add it as bookmark if you wish and click it when you want change numbers displayed :-) Might need some tweaking, though.

Comment: The JS worked without modification on version 2.9.  Looking forward to the persistent option in 2.10, though. Thanks.